# I can't change place of custom button in product page magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product

I have created Custom Button  using following Code at `addtocart.phtml`

```
<?php if($_product->getCustom_button()){ //yes or no button?>
        <button type="button"
                            title="<?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_name() ;?>"
                            class="action primary tocart"
                            onclick="window.open('<?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_url() ;?>')"><span><span><i class="icon-desktop"></i><?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_name() ;?></span></span></button>
        <?php } ?>
```

my custom button is below of add to cart button. I can't move custom button right side of custom button.[image]

Comment: pass the site url , can be fixed via css

Comment: try below css and make the text as icon , space is very less to adjust in same line

Answer (score 2):

Use following CSS to adjust the button at required place , however text is long for button and space is less so you should use icon instead

```
.product-add-form .product-options-bottom{
   float:left;
}
.product-info-main .product-options-bottom .box-tocart{
  float:left;
  width: 292px;
}
.product-info-main .live-preview{
   float:left;
   width:55px;
   margin:20px 0px;
}
```

Here you need this **live-preview** class or any class name in your button code.

[image]

**Add custom CSS in _extend.less** if not overriding original CSS  ( original can be changed in specific extended module )

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Less takes effect after upgrade/deploy commands

**Keep cache disabled**

let me know if any issue.

Thanks

Comment: please tell me file location of CSS for place  your code

Comment: added in answer, check updated ans

Comment: i have past your code at app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less   .  but button is still below side of add to cart button

Comment: Place in extend.less and run the commands

Comment: does it worked for you ?

Comment: no please send me email address i can share web login detail

Comment: kindly check your email i have send my hosting id detail .

Comment: I just sit to check  and your page seems worst now ... no buttons there ...I hope you are doing work on it